# Fidelity as bregman divergence

Tags: quantum-information, information-geometry

Fidelity is defined as follows:
$$F(\rho, \sigma) = \left( \operatorname{tr} \sqrt{\sqrt{\rho} \sigma \sqrt{\rho}} \right)^2$$

A Bregman divergence $D_B$ is defined as:
$$D_B(\rho||\sigma) = f(\rho) - f(\sigma) - \langle \nabla f(\sigma), \rho-\sigma\rangle$$

I am attempting to find an expression that represents fidelity in terms of a Bregman divergence. I have explored various methods to express fidelity using the Bures-Wasserstein distance and Rényi divergence, but so far, I have not achieved my goal. I specifically need this expression for mixed states of a two-level quantum system (qubit), but a general case would also be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

---

Edit:

I want to find $f$ and $<\cdot,\cdot>$ so:
$\left( \operatorname{tr} \sqrt{\sqrt{\rho} \sigma \sqrt{\rho}} \right)^2= f(\rho) - f(\sigma) - \langle \nabla f(\sigma), \rho-\sigma\rangle$

Comment: are you missing an operator under the square root?

Comment: Hi,
No operator is missing, I need f so I will be able to write expression of $D_B$ so it will equal to $F$

Comment: What's your motivation for this question? Do you have a strong reason to believe it is true?

Comment: Hello,

I have since discovered that my previous understanding was incorrect. Fidelity is indeed a concave function (sometimes strictly concave), while Bregman divergence is convex. My initial motivation was to expand upon the algorithm used in https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.08494 and apply it to fidelity calculations. However, it has become clear that this approach is not valid.